# Using jQuery autocomplete in my MVC3 application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm making a registration form for my users and I'd like them to write in their city.

So as they type in a city name, the auto-complete options of the [jQuery UI component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) would load asynchronously.

The example on the page shows how to use a .php file, but how does this fit into a pure HTTP solution?

How do I fetch these options?

I have a simple table accessed using Entity Framework and the repository pattern:

```
table City
------------------
CityId int primary key,
Name nvarchar(256)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The autocomplete plugin will send a GET request to the path you specify with a `?term=blah` querystring parameter.

You need to add an Action to your controller to handle this request, and return an array of matching values as json.

```
public ActionResult AutoCompleteCity(string term) {
  var db = new myEFDataContext();
  return Json(db.Cities.Where(city => city.Name.StartsWith(term)).Select(city => city.Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in your javascript you hook up the autcomplete function like so.

```
$('#cityTextBoxId').autocomplete({ source: '/Controller/AutoCompleteCity' });
```